# View files as binary in windows

Tags: windows

is there a tool to view files as **binary** in windows? actually i need the interpretation like 0010101010 not Hex Values !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex values are just a little bit compacted binary values. For example E represents 1110 etc. So you can use any hex editor to view and edit binary values.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Hex Editors :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 2):

Get [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) utilities. The `od` utility will do exactly what you need.